# Bilinear map is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $I,J$ two ideals.
I want to show that
$$
\begin{split}
\phi : \frac{R}{I} \times \frac{R}{J} &\rightarrow \frac{R}{I + J} \\
(i, j) &\mapsto ij
\end{split}
$$
is a well defined bilinear map.

Of course it is straightfoward that $\phi$ is bilinear.
But I don't arrive to show that $\phi$ is well-defined.
I know that I have to show for every $(i,j)=(k,l)$ in $R/I \times R/J$ then $ij=kl$ in $R/(I+J)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to show it is to show that $\phi(i, j)=\phi(i, l)=\phi(k, l)$, i.e. we change "one letter at a time". First, we have that
$$ ij-il = i(j-l) \in I \subset I+J, $$
and so $\phi(i, j) = \phi(i, l)$ in $R/(I+J)$. The other equality is completely analogous.